# Mosaico image upload and gallery error

Tags: wordpress, email, mosaico, imagick

When trying to upload an image to the Mosaico editor I get an internal server error and the image doesn't appear in the template nor in the gallery.

However, when I check the upload folder the image has actually been uploaded.
Also, when I compose a traditional mail I can see the images in the KC Finder.
Imagick is present on my server.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same problem & eventually just gave up on it. It must have to do with file permissions and the settings configuration, but I couldn't get anything to work.

Out of curiosity, who's hosting your site?

Comment: Siteground. They were very helpful configuring Imagick, but this didn't dolve the problem.

Comment: OK, then we're onto something. I'm also with Siteground . . . it must have something to do with the way they organize the filespace on the virtual servers. Or something . . .

Comment: Also check your .htaccess file to ensure the image directory is accessible.

Comment: All my issues regarding Mosaico images and placeholders seem to have been solved after upgrading to Mosaico 2.5.